# How to get parent key from child in Object

Tags: javascript

Given an Object, I want to get the parent key starting from the child. Since I only care about the key I'm iterating from enntries, but it always returns undefined.

```js
var book = {
    "chapter1": {
        "paragraph1": {
            "text": "..."
        },
        "paragraph2": {
            "text": "..."
        }
    },
    "chapter2": {
        "paragraph3": {
            "text": "..."
        },
        "paragraph4": {
            "text": "..."
        }
    },
    "chapter3": {
        "paragraph5": {
            "text": "..."
        },
        "paragraph6": {
            "text": "..."
        }
    }
};


var section = "paragraph3";

const category = Object.entries(book).find(([, e]) => Object.values(e).includes(section)); /// should return chapter2

if (category) {
    console.log(category[0], category[1]);
} else {
    console.log("Not Found");
}
```

Comment: You have no JSON here, only javascript objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `.values()` by `.keys()` in your code:

```js
  var book =  {
  "chapter1": {
    "paragraph1": {
      "text": "..."
    },
    "paragraph2": {
      "text": "..."
    }
  },
  "chapter2": {
    "paragraph3": {
      "text": "..."
    },
    "paragraph4": {
      "text": "..."
    }
  },
  "chapter3": {
    "paragraph5": {
      "text": "..."
    },
    "paragraph6": {
      "text": "..."
    }
  }
};


  var section = "paragraph3";

  const category = Object.entries(book).find(([, e]) => Object.keys(e).includes(section)); /// should return chapter2

  if (category) {
   console.log(category[0], category[1]);
  } else {
   console.log("Not Found");
  }
```

Comment: You beat me too it :) 

https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/ZEypqML?editors=0012

Answer (score -2):

here is a solution how to get parent key from children

```
var book = {
  chapter1: {
    paragraph1: {
      text: '...'
    },
    paragraph2: {
      text: '...'
    }
  },
  chapter2: {
    paragraph3: {
      text: '...'
    },
    paragraph4: {
      text: '...'
    }
  },
  chapter3: {
    paragraph5: {
      text: '...'
    },
    paragraph6: {
      text: '...'
    }
  }
};

var section = 'paragraph3';

const category = Object.entries(book).find(e =>
  Object.keys(e[1]).includes(section)
); /// should return chapter2

if (category) {
  console.log(category[0]);
} else {
  console.log('Not Found');
}
```

Comment: You should add the code here on this site.